# Suggestions for learning Objective-C and Cocoa

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I'd like to learn objective-c and Cocoa. I want yo to ask if you can recommend me any kind of thing to learn that language and the cocoa framework (For Mac OS X Development). I currently know PHP. Will be difficult to learn Obj-C coming from PHP?
PD: English is not first language, I have a quite good level. Would it be that difficult to learn with my knowledge of English?

Comment: You're going to need a reasonable grasp of technical English to do well in this field, but you seem to do well with English in your question, so I wouldn't worry about it.  You may or may not have to read more carefully than a native speaker; I've seen both.

Answer (score 2):

Excellent! It's inspiring to hear you want to learn some new programming languages.

Objective-C is an interesting language because it is a superset of ANSI-C that includes [Message Passing.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_passing) You may consider learning C first, because it will help you learn some computer science fundamentals that aren't relevant to PHP, and once you know C, Objective C is much easier to understand.

Also, I find that when learning a new language, it helps very much to understand some of the differences between them. (Forgive me if you already understand the following information or if it is too basic!)

- PHP is an interpreted language. Thus, every time you run a PHP script, the php binary or CGI perhaps decides what to do with each function call or statement you make in the script. On the other hand, C is a compiled language. This means that first you write C code, then "compile" it into assembly language (which is a written-language representation of machine code, more or less) and then you assemble it down to machine code (1's and 0's.)

  Thankfully, you don't have to do these steps yourself! The compiler and assembler do these. The point is that C code ultimately is transformed into a binary application that runs right on the computer's processor without being interpreted.
- You'll need to learn how to manage memory and data structures on your own. In PHP, memory for variables and structures is automatically allocated for you. In C or Objective-C, your application will need to do this using a function call or message. In addition, you will need to dispose of the memory when your application no longer needs the variable or data structure.
- PHP is what is called a "loosely" or "dynamically" typed language, meaning that checking a type of a variable (for the purposes of converting one type to another) is done while the script runs.

  On the other hand, C and Objective-C are (mostly) statically typed, which means that type conversions are checked when the application is compiled.
- Finally, Objective-C also has message passing, which is similar to a function call, although a message is always sent to an object.

There are many other differences as well, but these are some of the main ones. Feel free to comment with questions.

Also, to others, feel free to point out any errors or things I may have missed.

Comment: Thank you!! Can you recommend me any resource to learn Objective-C or I should use Apple's Objective-C tutorial??

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Tom's answer, I would say that you need a good understanding of memory allocation and pointers. These are new concepts coming from PHP.

I would recommend learning and practicing the different layers of memory management from simple to complex, and I would use other languages as a bridge from PHP to Objective-C:

- stack allocation (C)
- *raw* heap allocation: malloc() / free() (C)
- *smart* heap allocation: C++ new / delete (C++)
- *automatic* memory management based on references (C#)
- reference counting and garbage collection (Objective-C)

And the *tools* to handle that memory:

- value types, pointers and arrays (C)
- pointers to objects (C++)
- references (C++ and C#)

This will help you understand the difference between a block of memory and a pointer or reference that points to that block of memory.

Good Luck